# cleaning user input in asp.net (mvc3) to make it safe

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-input, validation

I need to accept user input (comments) in an asp.net mvc3 web application, which I then wish to re-display in the UI. I'd like to clean any XSS/script inclusion/hacking attempt/malicious code out of this comment text before saving it, and allowing it to be displayed on the screen. Is there a standard or generic method of doing this for .net?

I'd also like to be able to do things like - allow or disallow links, or nofollow links if they are allowed... etc.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Anti-XSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) library and have been happy with the results.

Comment: Chris, does this lib allow removing the parts that are unwanted and continue, or does it just throw an error when malicious scripts are identified? Last time I checked it seemed like it did the latter. thanks

Comment: Using it like this will clean the data and let you continue:

String Name = AntiXss.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["Name"]);

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout the [AntiXss library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/). It allows you to filter dangerous parts of HTML snippets such as malicious `<script>` tags that could be used to perform XSS attacks and produces safe to output HTML. There is also [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) (a bit outdated) about it on MSDN.